# My C code is producing unexpected output. Newline "\n" is producing unexpected output in 3 level inner loop

Tags: c, loops, printing, output, nested-loops

I am using Codelite IDE and when I use 2 nested loops the code works fine but when I use 3 nested loops it produces weird outputs like the '1' in the output image on the right side.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;

    for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
        for(j=1; j<=3; j++){
            for(k=1; k<=3; k++){
                printf("%d ", i);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing the space after `%d` in printf statement

Comment: I am [unable to reproduce this error](https://godbolt.org/z/Y36MT1hcr). Are you sure that the output that you are showing us is from the program code that you are showing us? What happens if you add a character to the output, for example by changing `printf("%d ", i);` to `printf("X%d ", i);`? Does it print the `X` and does the stray `1` at the right still appear?

Comment: Please don't post links to images of text. Post the text in the question, please.

Comment: @unwind: In this case, it is maybe appropriate to show an image, because the stray `1` at the right would be harder to see in a code block, because this would probably require scrolling.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it still produces a similar output, [link](https://imgur.com/a/f1R5iUE)

Comment: @ShrirangMahajan that didn't change anything

Comment: @unwind as Andreas pointed out, the stray '1' would have been hard to point out in that case

Comment: @AyushKaithwas: That is very strange. I suspect it may be a bug in your IDE. Do you have the same problem when you run your executable file directly, i.e. outside your Codelite IDE?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It is working as expected then. [link](https://imgur.com/a/Kt0Vyv7)

Comment: @AyushKaithwas: It does seem like a bug in CodeLite, then. Are you using the latest version of CodeLite? If not, then you may want to consider updating to the latest version, to see if the problem is fixed in that version.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I can't view the image (it's firewalled) so I wouldn't now. I'm pretty sure I can operate a scrollbar if I see a wide text box, though. :)

Comment: @unwind: I suppose it would be best to do both, then: Post it as an image as well as text.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Mega-meta-thread! :) Sure, but in that case it would be good to inline the image *in the question*, but I guess newish users can't do that. Not sure, though.